# Two-way ANOVA with weighted dependent variable

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, anova

Trying to compare 3 independent populations across the years by the size of their individuals, I have this kind of data set:

```
year <- c(rep(2000,5),rep(2001,3),rep(2002,7))
region <- c(1,1,2,3,3,1,2,3,rep(1,3),rep(2,3),3)
size <- c(28,24,26,56,47,85,12,24,68,71,42,59,12,25,33)
count <- c(3,8,9,1,2,4,7,12,4,8,3,2,7,15,4)
df <- data.frame(year, region, size, count)
```

Which gives:

```
year region size count
2000      1   28     3
2000      1   24     8
2000      2   26     9
2000      3   56     1
2000      3   47     2
2001      1   85     4
2001      2   12     7
2001      3   24    12
2002      1   68     4
2002      1   71     8
2002      1   42     3
2002      2   59     2
2002      2   12     7
2002      2   25    15
2002      3   33     4
```

I want to make a 2-Way ANOVA:

```
model.2way <- lm(size ~ year * region, df)  # example of code
anova(model.2way)
```

My issue is that the variable `size` is weighted by `count`: for each `size`, I have `count` number of individuals. I got millions of data and can't easily transform my data to have millions of `size` values.

Do you know a way to make a 2-Way ANOVA with this kind of weighted data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
model.2way <- lm(size ~ year * region, df, weights = count)
```

From `?lm`:

> ... when the elements of ‘weights’ are positive integers w_i, that each response y_i is the mean of w_i unit-weight observations ...

In other words, a weight of 2 means that case appears twice.